# Upgrading to developer edition from SQL Server 2022 Evaluation edition

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, sql-server-2022

I ran an inplace upgrade of a SQL Server 2019 Developer to SQL Server 2022 Evaluation on our dev environment in June. The evaluation period now has expired, so I tried to run an edition upgrade via the setup.exe wizard tool. The tool runs succesfully, but it only upgrades the features:SQL Browser,SQL Writer - the database engine is not listed. It still says "SQL Server evaluation period has expired" when I try to start the service.
It says Developer Edition in the log and in the wizard for my instance - so it's like it assumes it's not an evaluation version.

How can I force it to upgrade the database engine?

I use the SQL2022-SSEI-Dev.exe

Comment: Since it's just a dev environment and my problem reminds me about a downgrading issue I decided to switch to the right developer edition via a reinstall and copying my system databases back in place. I just followed this guide https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/downgrading-sql-server-editions/

It's working fine now.